# Wordpress JS files are loading twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to include Bootstrap 4 to my WordPress installation. This is how I include it within my `functions.php` in the child theme.

```
// Bootstrap 4
function bootstrap() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-slim', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js', array(), '3.2.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery-slim'), '4.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery-slim'), '4.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');
```

When I test my site on pingdom or GTMetrix they say it is loaded twice. Why?

```
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 68.0KiB.

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js?ver=3.2.1

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.0.0
```

The parent theme is not loading any of these files. But why is e.g. the popper.js not loading twice?

Comment: can you comment `wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js',......` and see if bootstrap.js is loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, WP itself includes jquery and bootstrap, and if you want yours specific ones you should deregister the core/default ones, then register yours (without jquery and bootstrap it wont do much):

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery'); //because its a Core-Registered Script
wp_register_script('jquery', 'THE PATH TO THE FILE', array(), '', FALSE);
```

The answer is here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/284620

Comment: WordPress **not** include jQuery and Bootstrap in default. It only include when the themes/plugins enqueue it.

Comment: I am using WP Rocket and after disabling the plugin the js files were included only once. So instead of using ´wp_enqueue_script´ I used ´wp_register_script´ and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The double loading of Javascript and CSS files can be the result of a browser extension.

So **before adding tons of hooks to your `functions.php` file**, try to disable your browser extensions one by one to see if this solves the problem.

Target in particular development extensions like for example ***[CSS Auto Reload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-auto-reload/fiikhcfekfejbleebdkkjjgalkcgjoip)*** which will have exactly this effect on the loading of your pages.

I know it's an old thread, but I think it's never too late to give an answer on StackOveflow and hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer likely saved me hours of work. It was an extension, perhaps a combo of them that caused the effect.  The  "Dark mode" extension may be the culprit.